# How does Facebook chat tcp connection keep alive?

Tags: facebook, xmpp, chat, offline

I implemented a XMPP chat client with Facebook Chat API, it can log in and chat.
But I found Facebook chat XMPP server doesn't support XEP-0199.
So if client doesn't send or receive message for a long time(tcp connection is idle), client will be offline.

How does Facebook chat tcp connection keep alive?

Answer (score 4):

There's a practice in XMPP of sending a single space character at some interval.  This keeps the TCP connection alive.

[XMPP-Core section 4.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-4.6) describes issues related to this.